# Can an Android tablet connected to my computer via USB hit a REST endpoint that is running on my computer?

Tags: android, rest, local, tablet

here's my scenario. I have some REST endpoints that I'm running locally on my machine (http://myip:port/getdata). Given NO internet connectivity (no wifi, hot spot, or tethering options), is it possible for an Android tablet that is connected to my machine via USB cable to hit that endpoint?

Comment: If you have the device connected via USB for your testing, try replacing the 'myip' with 'localhost' first to see if that works. If it does not, I believe you will need to be on the same local or wifi network before the localhost will recognize it.